# Navigating long un-ordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, keyboard, html-lists

I have this long list with overflow: auto to scroll through it, i set it up for keyboard navigation, the problem is that when using the keyboard it doesn't scroll correctly!

check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Akoud/p6243/6/)

```
$('ul').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { // up
        var selected = $(".selected");
        $listItems.removeClass("selected");
        if (selected.prev().length == 0) {
            selected.siblings().last().addClass("selected");
        } else {
            selected.prev().addClass("selected");
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down
        var selected = $(".selected");
        $listItems.removeClass("selected");
        if (selected.next().length == 0) {
            selected.siblings().first().addClass("selected");
        } else {
            selected.next().addClass("selected");
        }
    }
})
});
$listItems.click(function () {
if ($(this).is('.selected')) {
    return true;
} else {
    $('li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
}
```

the behavior i'm looking for is the same behavior of the  element when scrolling through a long list of  elements using the keyboard this plugin [SelectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/#LongLists) show's what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code instead, i used animate function to navigate inside the div if the list exceed the width of the ul tag :

http://jsfiddle.net/goldendousa/p6243/13/

```
$('ul').focus(function() {
    if ($('ul li').is('.selected')) {
        $('ul li').first().removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $('ul li').first().addClass('selected');
    }
});
$('ul').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38) { // up
        e.preventDefault();
        var selected = $(".selected");
        $("ul li").removeClass("selected");
        if (selected.prev().length == 0) {
            selected.siblings().last().addClass("selected");           
            var selectedTopOffset = selected.siblings().last().offset().top;

                $('div').animate({
                    scrollTop: selectedTopOffset
                }, 200);

        } else {
            selected.prev().addClass("selected");

            var selectedTopOffset = $("div").scrollTop() + selected.position().top - $("div").height()/2 + selected.height()/2;

                $('div').animate({
                    scrollTop: selectedTopOffset
                }, 200);


        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { // down
        e.preventDefault();
        var selected = $(".selected");
        $("ul li").removeClass("selected");
        if (selected.next().length == 0) {
            selected.siblings().first().addClass("selected");

            if (selected.siblings().first().offset().top < 0) {
                $('div').animate({
                    scrollTop: selected.siblings().first().offset().top
                }, 200);
            }

        } else {

            selected.next().addClass("selected");


            var selectedTopOffset = $("div").scrollTop() + selected.position().top - $("div").height()/2 + selected.height()/2;

                $('div').animate({
                    scrollTop: selectedTopOffset
                }, 200);

        }
    }
});

$('li').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is('.selected')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $('li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```